# Tracking change in order of elements inside array - Angular 10

Tags: angular, ngfor

I’d like to track the position of elements inside an array to show if a the position of an element went up, down or it is a new element when the array changes.

Those elements are retrieved with a query to a server. The first query retrieves the first N elements and those should be displayed as **new**. The second query can retrieve the same documents in different order, completely new elements, or both. The new elements should display **new**. If an element was already existing but changed position, I would like to know if it went **up **or **down**.

I was thinking of using the trackBy function of the ngFor but I’m not really sure how I can proceed.

Answer (score 0):

This is a suggestion of how to implement what you mention

**EDUCATIVE EXAMPLE**

First, we are going to create an interface to the objects that come from the array.
We are going to add the state attribute, to know how it varies the position in the different calls

```
interface ArrayData { 
    id:number;
    title:string;
    state?:number; // Add a state property;
  }
```

Then, we are going to create an enum, with the different states

```
  enum STATES {
    NEW,
    UP,
    DOWN,
    NOT_CHANGED
}
```

In the class, i explain the rest

```
export class YourClass {

  public arrayData: ArrayData[] = [];
  constructor(private myService: MyService){}

  public getArrayData(){
    this.myService.getArrayData().subscribe((data: ArrayData[]) => {
        // We are going to process the response data.
        this.arrayData = this.setUpDownNewElements(data);
    })
  }

  private setUpDownNewElements(data: ArrayData[]): ArrayData[]{
    //  loop through the new array elements 
    data.forEach((element:ArrayData, index: number) => { 
         //  find last index
        const lastIndex = this.arrayData.findIndex(lastItem => lastItem.id === element.id)
        //  Check if the index exist
        if(lastIndex === -1){ 
            //There is a new element, so we are going to change the state of the element to NEW
            element.state = STATES.NEW;
        }
        else if(lastIndex === index){
            // not position changed
            element.state = STATES.NOT_CHANGED;
        }
        else{
            // check down up position
            element.state = lastIndex < index ? STATES.UP : STATES.DOWN
        }       
    })
  return data;
  }
}
```

now you have an array of objects, that each object contains the state that indicates what situation it is in with respect to the previous round